# Как получить случайным образом k заведомо неповторяющихся элементов множества из n элементов?

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Как получить случайным образом `k` заведомо неповторяющихся элементов множества из `n` элементов?

Например, я реализую некоторую программу и мне нужны `N` **разных** чисел, но генератор случайных чисел не дает такой гарантии. Что делать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**: просто генерируем случайные не повторяющиеся индексы.

#### Теория

Генераторы псевдослучайных чисел (ГПСЧ) выдают периодическую последовательность чисел. Некоторые ГПСЧ позволяют обойти все элементы множества `{0, 1, ..., N}` без пропусков.

Самый простой такой ГПСЧ - это линейный конгруэнтный генератор:

```
x = (x * a + c) % m
```

Например для `a=5`, `c=1`, `m=8` он выдает последовательность

```
0, 1, 6, 7, 4, 5, 2, 3,  0, 1, 6, 7, 4, 5, 2, 3,  ...
```

Для того чтобы ЛКГ перебирал все числа в интервале `[0, m)`, его параметры должны удовлетворять следующим условиям:

1. `m` и `c` должны быть взаимно простые;
2. `a - 1` должно делиться на все простые делители `m`;
3. `a - 1` должно делиться на `4` если `m` делится на `4`.

Если нам надо сделать ГСПЧ с произвольным периодом N, то не обязательно делать `m == N` и подбирать `a` и `c` по правилам выше. Можно сделать

```
m = pow(2, floor(log2(10)+1)) // ближайшая степень двойки больше N
a = 5 // лучше найти ближайшее простое число меньше m
c = 1
```

И написать ГСПЧ, который просто будет отбрасывать числа которые не входят в интервал `[0, N)`:

```
uint seed = 0;
uint prng(uint N) {
  uint m = 1 << floor(log2(N)+1);
  do {
    seed = (seed * 5 + 1) % m;
  } while(seed >= N);
  return seed;
}
```

#### Практика

Нам надо сгенерировать `k` не повторяющихся чисел из интервала `[0, N)`.
Берем ГСПЧ с периодом `N` и генерируем `k` чисел.

Линейный конгруэнтный генератор страдает корреляциями, по этому чтобы улучшить выдачу, эти `k` чисел можно положить в массив и дополнительно перемешать при помощи `std::shuffle`.

Вот пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>

class Generator {
public:
    Generator(unsigned N) : n_(N), m_((1 << unsigned(log2(N) + 1)) - 1) {}

    const std::vector<unsigned>& generate(unsigned k) {
        data_.resize(k);
        for (auto& x : data_) {
            do {
                seed_ = (seed_ * 5 + 1) & m_;
            } while (seed_ >= n_);

            x = seed_;
        }
        std::shuffle(begin(data_), end(data_), shuffle_gen_);
        return data_;
    }
private:
    unsigned n_;
    unsigned m_;
    unsigned seed_ = 0;
    std::vector<unsigned> data_;
    std::mt19937 shuffle_gen_;
};

int main() {
    Generator g(100500);
    for (auto x : g.generate(10)) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Алгоритмы, приводившиеся [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/760153/n-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-stdset), решают эту задачу, требуя только `O(k)` памяти.

Задача выборки из контейнера с последовательным доступом решена по ссылке. Задача выборки `k` чисел из диапазона `[0, n)` решается так же, подразумевая, что мы делаем выборку из "виртуального контейнера", в котором i-тый элемент равен `i`

- "Алгоритм Кнута"

  ```
  int main()
  {
    const unsigned K = 3, N = 10;
    std::vector<int> r;

    for (unsigned i = 0, k = K; i < N && k > 0; ++i)
      if (rand() % (N - i) < k)
      {
        r.push_back(i);
        --k;
      }

    std::copy(r.begin(), r.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  ```
- Алгоритм "резервуарной выборки"

  ```
  int main()
  {
    const unsigned K = 3, N = 10;

    std::vector<int> r(K);
    std::iota(r.begin(), r.end(), 0);

    for (unsigned i = K; i < N; ++i)
      if (rand() % (i + 1) < K)
        r[rand() % K] = i;

    std::copy(r.begin(), r.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  ```

  Как отмечено по ссылке, этот алгоритм при принятии решения об элементе не использует значения `n`. Т.е. этому алгоритму не нужно знать `n` заранее - на каждой итерации он поддерживает равномерно распределенную случайную выборку для "текущего" значения `n`, т.е. количества просмотренных/прочитанных/полученных на данный момент элементов.

Как и прежде, следует заметить, что эти алгоритмы выбирают случайные элементы исходного набора, но располагают их в неслучайном порядке в результирующем наборе. Если порядок тоже нужен случайный, то результат следует дополнительно случайно перетасовать.

Вышеприведенные алгоритмы требуют только `O(k)` рамяти, но решают задачу за время `O(n)`, что неоптимально в случаях, когда `k << n`.

- Алгоритм Боба Флойда, упоминающийся и "Жемчужинах программирования" работает эффективнее в таких случаях, но требует дополнительной [эффективной] структуры данных для определения того, что элемент уже выбирался

  ```
  int main()
  {
    const unsigned K = 3, N = 100;
    std::unordered_set<int> r;

    for (unsigned i = N - K; i < N; ++i)
    {
      unsigned j = rand() % (i + 1);
      r.insert(r.find(j) == r.end() ? j : i);
    }

    std::copy(r.begin(), r.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  ```

  Обратите внимание, что этот алгоритм не является примитивным алгоритмом "проб и ошибок" - он гарантирует добавление нового случайного элемента на каждой итерации. Т.е. для значений `k` близких к `n` он не будет "почти зацикливаться" (как это происходит с наивными алгоритмами), а найдет решение ровно за `k` итераций.

Comment: При K = 3, N = 65536 первые два алгоритма неэффективны (проще запоминать уже отобранные элементы). Третий алгоритм производит перебор на каждой итерации.

Comment: @Yuri Negometyanov: Разумеется, как и сказано в ответе, первые два неэффективны при таких условиях. Но где вы увидели "перебор на каждой итерации" в третьем мне не ясно. Среднее/амортизированное время поиска-добавления в хэш-таблицу - `O(1)`.

Comment: r.find(j) == r.end()

Comment: И? Еще раз: среднее/амортизированное время поиска-добавления в хэш-таблицу - `O(1)`. Никакого перебора. Не говоря уже о том, что даже если тут зачем-то умышленно сделать "перебор", то это будет `O(k)` перебор.

Comment: Т.е. генерация хэш-кода, плюс пара записей в "маленькую" хэш-таблицу - это не "катастрофические потери"? Ведь "одного присваивания более чем достаточно"... Двойные стандарты, однако...

Comment: @Yuri Negometyanov: Вы видимо что-то не понимаете. Ключевой момент в "одного присваивания более чем достаточно" - плохое кэш-поведение кода, то есть *нелокальность* доступа к памяти. Как я сказал, именно манера кода "лупить" в непредсказуемые точки большого региона памяти создают проблему. Здесь же ничего такого нет. Здесь хешируются не более `k` элементов. Все очень компактно и локально.

Comment: Да, я не понимаю двойных стандартов.

Answer (score 1):

UPD.

1. Создать массив A из `n` чисел.
2. Сгенерировать случайный индекс `p` в диапазоне `0...n-1`.
3. Отобрать элемент A<sub>p</sub>.
4. Сделать замену в массиве: A<sub>p</sub> = A<sub>n-1</sub>.
5. Декрементировать n: `n--;`
6. Если требуемое количество элементов не набрано, то перейти к п.2.

Если вместо замены элемента по п.4 производить обмен и дополнительно запоминать индексы p, то можно работать и по исходному массиву (с последующим восстановлением в обратном порядке).

Comment: Такой подход требует создания массива из `n` элементов, когда нас интересует только `k` элементов результата. Вся суть такой задачи как раз и заключается в том, чтобы обойтись `O(k)` памяти,  а не `O(n)`.

Comment: @AnT Если множество - не интервал, то без массива не обойтись. А если интервал, то можно завести массив использованных элементов. Но главная идея (сжатие интервала выборки) остаётся.

Comment: Как это "не обойтись"? Существует бесчисленное множество способов представить "не интервал". Это не обязательно массив. Но даже если множество представлено массивом, то 1) этот массив живет вне алгоритма, 2) этот массив не разрешается модифицировать без явного на то разрешения.

Comment: Алгоритм "резервуарной выборки" - хороший пример алгоритма, который не требует произвольного доступа к элементам множества и предварительного знания их общего количества. Ему нужен лишь один *последовтельный* проход по этим элементам.

Comment: @AnT При этом память разменивается на быстродействие.

Comment: Нет, наоборот. Асимптотически быстродействие то же самое, а на практике получается намного лучше, ибо алгоритм не занимается выделением ненужного неоправданно большого блока памяти и неэффективным (с точки зрения процессорного кэша) ползанием по нему.

Comment: Кстати, у вас в описании алгоритма вообще никак не фигурирует `k`. То есть пока что написана бессмыслица.

Comment: @AnT Одно присваивание на один элемент - это фатальная потеря? Кстати, сейчас мы говорим не о "моём" прозрачном алгоритме, а об альтернативах.

Comment: С точки зрения кэш-поведения кода? О, да! Если алгоритм "лупит" чтениями и записями по случайным местам в большом регионе памяти, то потери будут *катастрофические*. "Одного присваивания" более чем достаточно.