# N случайных элементов из std::set

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть `std::set` минимум из **N** элементов. *Как выбрать **N** разных случайных?*
Порядок любой.

Comment: Что значит "N разных случайных"? Порядок элементов в выборке тоже должен быть случайным? Или случайными долны быть только элементы, а относительный порядок можно сохранить как в set?

Comment: Порядок любой. Случайные сами элементы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если постановка задачи требует именно работы на структуре данных с последовательным доступом, то классический "алгоритм Кнута" подойдет прекрасно: проходим последовательно по элементам `std::set` и принимаем решение брать очередной элемент с вероятностью `осталось набрать элементов / осталось пройти элементов`

```
int main()
{
    std::set<int> s = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    unsigned N = 3;
    std::vector<int> r;

    auto it = s.begin();
    for (unsigned S = s.size(); S > 0 && N > 0; --S, ++it)
      if (rand() % S < N)
      {
        r.push_back(*it);
        --N;
      }

    std::copy(r.begin(), r.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Такой алгоритм выполнит случайную выборку `N` элементов с сохранением их относительного порядка из исходного `std::set`. Если порядок тоже надо получить случайный, то можно просто дополнительно сделать случайную перетасовку полученной выборки.

Другим вариантом будет алгоритм ["резервуарной выборки"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling), согласно которому мы сначала сразу забираем `N` первых элементов из `std::set` в нашу выборку, а затем итерируем через оставшиеся элементы `std::set` (начиная с элемента с номером `i = N`). Каждый новый элемент мы забираем в выборку с вероятностью `N / (i + 1)` и сохраняем в случайную позицию в выборке

```
int main()
{
    std::set<int> s = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    unsigned N = 3;
    std::vector<int> r;

    auto it = s.begin();
    unsigned i = 0;

    for (; i < N; ++i, ++it)
      r.push_back(*it);

    for (; it != s.end(); ++i, ++it)
      if (rand() % (i + 1) < N)
        r[rand() % N] = *it;

    std::copy(r.begin(), r.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Такой алгоритм уже не будет сохранять относительный порядок элементов в выборке. Однако из-за того, что первые `N` элементов выбраны по порядку, полной случайности порядка и тут нет.

Интересной особенностью варианта "резервуарной выборки" является то, что ему не нужно знать размера исходной последовательности заранее, т.е. его можно использовать для генерации случайной выборки из последовательности, генерируемой неким "оракулом", не зная заранее, когда эта последовательность закончится. (Например, для случайной выборки строк из текстового файла нет необходимости знать заранее, сколько в этом файле строк.)

---

Если бы исходный контейнер поддерживал эффективный прямой доступ по индексу элемента (т.е. если бы это был массив, а не `std::set`), то такие подходы были бы довольно неэффективными в ситуациях, когда `N` намного меньше, чем размер исходного контейнера. Но в случае `std::set` это соображение неприменимо.

Answer (score 1):

Если воспользоваться дополнительным вектором - просто: выбираем в нем эти N элементов, а потом берем соответствующие из множества.

Вряд ли вы будете работать с ними прямо во множестве - скорее всего, вы будете использовать либо копии элементов, либо итераторы/указатели, на них указывающие. В таком случае можно просто загрузить их в вектор, перемешать и выбрать первые N, например.

Если вы уточните, как вы планируете их использовать - можно будет уточнить способ :)

Comment: Мне нужно выбрать несколько элементов и скопировать их в другой массив. В принципе, скорость не играет особой роли, так что подойдет любое решение. Я просто думал, что есть библиотечная(в stl или boost) функция.

Comment: Нет, в `set` нужно идти последовательно. А тасовать множество нельзя - в нем элементы всегда упорядочены.

Answer (score 1):

используйте  альгоритм  std::random_shuffle или  std::next_permutation

Comment: К чему вы его предлагаете применить? К `set`?

Comment: почему к set? Разве так трудно скопировать  например в  std::list ?...

Comment: Еслиб я задавал вопрос, то мне не нужны были бы подробности,  для получения ответа не тривиальные вещи важны, а суть...

Comment: *Приходит заяц к сове. Сова, говорит, посоветуй, как мне с волками справиться? совсем обложили... Да просто, - говорит Сова. - Берешь автомат Калашникова, прячешься в засаду и кладешь всю волчью стаю. Заяц в ступоре: Сова, но где ж я автомат возьму?! - Заяц, - говорит Сова поучительно. - Я стратег, а со своими тактическими вопросами разбирайся сам!*

Comment: хороший анекдот. За юмор респект, но  если ты прочел внимательно, то обратил бы внимание на слово "тривиальные", а где брать зайцу автомат калашникова  не имеет связи с тривиальностью. Я подсказал где брать автомат - отмеченные мной альгоритмы, я не посказал просто как подойти и как стрелять. По моему так...

Comment: Оставляю на вашей (мне комфортнее с незнакомыми людьми быть на "вы") совести совет применить алгоритмы, которые к заданному в вопросе контейнеру неприменимы... Вы даже не предложили первоначально скопировать в другой контейнер. В общем, как я понимаю, каждый остался при своем мнении, так что "закончим эту бесполезную дискуссию. Сестра, включи телевизор погромче!" (с)