# Как работает этот код? (репрезентативная выборка)

Tags: java, алгоритм, статический-анализ

Есть волшебный код:

```
static int samplerSize = 50;
static int[] sampler = new int[50];
static int i;

public static void samplerProces(int value)
{
    if (i < samplerSize)
    {
        sampler[i++]=value;
        return;
    }

    double p = samplerSize/(double)i++;
    if (rand.nextDouble() < p)
    {
        sampler[rand.nextInt(samplerSize)] = value;
    }
}

public static void test()
{
    int[] data = IntStream.range(0, 10000).toArray();
    IntStream.of(data).forEach(e -> {samplerProces(e);});
    System.out.println(IntStream.of(sampler).average());
}
```

Каким-то волшебным образом average находится рядом с 5000, что означает, что в выборке находятся элементы со всего массива с одним шансом.

Каким образом, ума не приложу, ведь, судя по коду, чем ближе к концу, тем процент меньше...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это классический [алгоритм Резервуарной Выборки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). В вашем случае у вас 50 резервуаров.

См.также
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/760167/182825
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/780834/182825

---

Рассмотрите его, например, для случая 1 резервуара: мы проходим по последовательности входных данных (заранее не зная ее длины) и "берем" элемент данных с вероятностью `1/i`, где `i` - номер элемента (нумерация с 1). Всякий раз, когда мы принимаем решение "взять" новый элемент, мы забываем про "взятый" ранее.

Как видите, вероятность "взятия" элемента становится все меньше и меньше, по мере того, как мы продвигаемся дальше и дальше. Тем не менее в результате, дойдя до конца последовательности, мы будем иметь равновероятно выбранный элемент. Ничего удивительного в этом на самом деле нет, даже если сначала это выглядит неинтуитивно.

- На первом шаге алгоритма мы "берем" первый элемент с вероятностью 1.
- На втором шаге алгоритма мы "берем" второй элемент с вероятностью 1/2.

  Вероятность получения в итоге первого элемента равна вероятности его "взятия" на первом шаге, умноженной на вероятность "не взятия" второго элемента на втором шаге: 1 * 1/2 = 1/2.

  Вероятность получения в итоге второго элемента равна вероятности его "взятия": 1/2.

  Как видите вероятности равны.
- На третьем шаге алгоритма мы "берем" третий элемент с вероятностью 1/3.

  Вероятность получения в итоге первого элемента равна вероятности его "взятия" на первом шаге, умноженной на вероятность "не взятия" второго элемента на втором шаге и на вероятность "не взятия" третьего элемента на третьем шаге: 1 * 1/2 * 2/3 = 1/3.

  Вероятность получения в итоге второго элемента равна вероятности его "взятия" на втором шаге, умноженной на вероятность "не взятия" третьего элемента на третьем шаге: 1/2 * 2/3 = 1/3.

  Вероятность получения в итоге третьего элемента равна вероятности его "взятия": 1/3.

  Как видите все вероятности снова равны.
- На четвертом шаге алгоритма мы берем четвертый элемент с вероятностью 1/4. Вероятности получения в итоге каждого пройденного элемента равны

  ```
  1: 1 * 1/2 * 2/3 * 3/4 = 1/4
  2: 1/2 * 2/3 * 3/4 = 1/4
  3: 1/3 * 3/4 = 1/4
  4: 1/4
  ```

  Все вероятности по-прежнему равны.

И.т.д. после каждого `i`-го шага, вычислив вероятности получения каждого из просмотренных элементов, вы обнаружите, что все они оказались равны `1/i`. То есть на каждом шаге поддерживается равновероятная выборка одного элемента из уже пройденной части последовательности.

Общий алгоритм Резервуарной Выборки - лишь обобщение этого подхода на случай множественной выборки.